# Scala AST avoid traversal of Tree children

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, abstract-syntax-tree, scalac

I am working on a scalac plugin in which I am traversing the AST. Right now I am using a for each loop over the `unit.body`, which I get from the passed `Global` value. The issue I am facing is that due to the recursive nature of said for each traversal, I visit each `Tree` and its children, though I do not want to traverse the latter since I am using pattern matching to match for function calls.

So for example if I would traverse the statement:

```
x.do(arg1)(arg2)(arg3)
```

I will get the following things in my traversal:

```
1. x.do(arg1)(arg2)(arg3)
2.    x.do(arg1)(arg2)
3.        x.do(arg1)
4.            x.do
5.                x
6.                do
7.            arg1
8.        arg2
9.    arg3
```

Here I indented the `Tree` objects in order of traversal. Now if I would use the `Apply` case class to match with each of these, I would get a match out of 1,2, and 3, while I really only want 1. I thought about using a context sensitive solution (like check against the previous traversed `Tree`) but it is not consistent enough for my purposes. I am also not looking for specific methods, which would make matching easier, but for methods in general, but I cannot allow for these children to be counted.

Is there a better pattern I can match function calls with when writing a scalac plugin, or a better way to do the traversal, so that I do not run into this recursion issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:
Instead of using the intuitive

`for(tree <- treeObject)`, where `treeObject : Tree`

You can just use the `children` object in each `Tree` object and do the following

```
def func(treeObject : Tree) : Something = {
    for(tree <- treeObject.children) {
        if(/*your condition for further traversal*/)
            func(treeObject : Tree) //RECURSE
        else
            someValue //do whatever and RETURN
    }
}
```

With this approach you can set a stopping condition for traversal. So let's say you only want to look at each method invocation. A method invocation can be matched for using the `Apply` case class. Now you can just check whether or not your current `tree` matches with that pattern. If it does you do your work on it and return. If it is not traverse the `Tree` further by using recursion, to get possible method invocations further "down".